# warning: unknown escape sequence '\

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to run a regex through a system command in the code, I have gone through the threads in StackOverflow on similar warnings but I couldn't understand on how to fix the below warnings, it seems to come only for the closed brackets on doing \\}. The warnings seem to disappear but not able to get the exact output in the redirected file.

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(){

        FILE *in;
        char buff[512];

if(system("grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' /home/santosh/Test/text >t2.txt") < 0){
                printf("system failed:");
                exit(1);
        }
}
```

Warnings:

```
dup.c:9:11: warning: unknown escape sequence '\}'
dup.c:9:11: warning: unknown escape sequence '\}'
dup.c:9:11: warning: unknown escape sequence '\}'
dup.c:9:11: warning: unknown escape sequence '\}'
dup.c: In function 'main':
```

Comment: You don't need to escape curly braces in C string literals.

Comment: @Downvoter, true, but `grep` wants this sintaxis (`[x-y]\{x,y}`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C string literals the `\` has a special meaning, it's for representing characters such as line endings `\n`. If you want to put a `\` in a string, you need to use `\\`.

For example

```
"\\Hello\\Test"
```

will actually result in "\Hello\Test".

So your regexp needs to be written as:

```
"[0-9]\\{1,3\}\\\\.[0-9]\\{1,3\}\\\\.[0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\\\.[0-9]\\{1,3\\}"
```

instead of:

```
"[0-9]\{1,3\}\\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\\.[0-9]\{1,3\}"
```

Sure this is painful because `\` is used as escape character for the regexp and again as escape character for the string literal.

So basically: when you want to put a `\` you need to write `\\`.

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: Forgot two `\\` s. Question has been edited. Try again.